# Summarize values in a list by index Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, iteration

I have a list of indexes:

```
list = [13,28,59,69]
```

I also have a list of values I need to sum:

```
[values] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18, etc etc]
```

I need to summarize all values until index 13, then summarize all values until index 28 minus the 13, etc etc.

Anyone has an easy way to accomplish this?

I tried to iterate through the values list, and iterate through the index list, and saying if 13>n, then summarize everything before hand, but was having difficulty.

Comment: `I tried to iterate through the values list, and iterate through the index list, and saying if 13>n, then summarize everything before hand, but was having difficulty.`: (1) What have you tried? Post your code, and (2) what was the difficulty? Post the error.

Comment: why is the final value in `list` = 10 ?  it should be a number > the previous number which is 59.   Please clarify this....

Comment: @D.L typo; changed

Comment: okay, this makes sense.  Answer posted...

Comment: Don't name a variable `list`, it hides the builtin type's `list()` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

One good approach would be to use `index slicing` and resetting the slices according to the first list.

The answer uses *an example sum function*, but the OP can deploy any function...

So this would work:

```py
my_list = [3,5,10,15]
my_values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]

u = 0
for v in my_list:
    my_sum = sum(my_values[u:v])
    print(f'the sum from {u} to {v} is: ', my_sum)
    u = v
```

result:

```
the sum from 0 to 3 is:  6
the sum from 3 to 5 is:  9
the sum from 5 to 10 is:  40
the sum from 10 to 15 is:  65
```